# ORA-08102: index key not found, obj# 194450, file 51, block 10623 (2) ORA-02063: preceding line from LIVEPAY

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, toad

I ran a delete query in asp.net c# but it gives following error 
ORA-08102: index key not found, obj# 194450, file 51, block 10623 (2) ORA-02063: preceding line from LIVEPAY

but ran the query on toad it works fine on toad.
any help will be highly appriciated
thanks
 Here is query i ran "delete * from leaves where app_no ='xxxxxx'"

Comment: I think you might want to talk to your dba, you might have some index corruption, s/he can run the dbv utility to check for bad blocks.  You might want to drop and recreate the index that is giving an error, you can use dba_objects to find the index using the obj#

Comment: recreated index. but the problem still there.

Comment: OK, I think it is time for you to call your dba.  One other thing you could try, you could try to create it in a different tablespace, probably that won't fix it but if it is some wierd disk error that might fix it, do you know the tablespace clause on the create index?  Also double check that you rebuilt the right index (select * from dba_objects where object_id=(object id from error))

Answer (score 0):

Include the RowID in the select set.  RDMSs need to be able to absolutely uniquely identify the row to delete.  This field is present, but usually not displayed.